# django.contrib.auth.models.User.profile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile

Tags: django, django-models

**My models.py file looks like:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

When I'm trying to look it into the shell:

```
>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.filter(username='TestUser').first()
>>> user
<User: TestUser>
>>> user.profile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Visual Studio Code Projects\cs50\Learning Django(other source)\Corey\djangoenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 423, in __get__
    self.related.get_accessor_name()
django.contrib.auth.models.User.profile.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile.
```

I looked various different tutorials and solutions it works fine for everyone.
Please help me with this regards, really stuck at this point.

Comment: Well since your user has no related `Profile`, it will indeed error. Where did you create a `Profile` for the given `User`?

Comment: Sorry, this question is not valid it was my mistake there please don't follow the question

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a userprofile for the user first:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

In your views.py you can use get_or_create so that a userprofile is created for a user if the user doesn't have one.

```
user, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```